# How to stop worker threads in a multithreaded Windows service on service stop

Tags: .net, multithreading, windows-services

I have a Windows service that uses the producer/consumer queue model with multiple worker threads processing tasks off a queue. These tasks can be very long running, in the order of many minutes if not hours, and *do not involve loops*.

My question is about the best way to handle the service stop to gracefully end processing on these worker threads. I have read in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353270/how-can-i-detect-a-threadabortexception-in-a-finally-block-net) that using thread.Abort() is a sign of bad design, but it seems that the service OnStop() method is only given a limited amount of time to finish before the service is terminated. I can do sufficient clean-up in the catch for ThreadAbortException (there is no danger of inconsistent state) so calling thread.Abort() on the worker threads seems OK to me. Is it? What are the alternatives?

Comment: any final solution with source code sample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, `Abort` should be avoided. It would be best to give them some time to exit gracefully - then perhaps after a timeout, **maybe** consider aborting them - but ultimately, service stop can do that just the same by killing the process instead.

I would try to have a signal in my queues that says "flush and exit" - much like the `Close` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net/530228#530228), but with some kind of signal when complete.

If you resort to `Abort` - consider the process fatally wounded. Kill it ASAP.

Comment: The worker process is very long running (I've clarified this in the question) so waiting is usually not an option.

Answer (score 5):

Create a task type for "shutdown" and inject that into your producer/consumer queue once for each worker thread.

Then use Thread.Join (with a timeout) to ensure shutdown has completed.

Comment: The worker process is very long running so putting messages on the queue will not work most of the time (I'm doing this anyway just in case)

Comment: So the flag approach is likely better, and then the jobs need to check this flag regularly (and, possibly, save the remainder of the job).

Answer (score 2):

With .NET 4.0 you can utilize the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace to take advantage of the `Task` object.  In a nutshell, you can assign a `CancellationToken` to more gracefully handle cancellations/aborts in tasks, be it long or short running.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx) for more details from MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

The question as amended actually has less to do with threading and more to do with how to stop long running actions. Personally I always use APM for lengthy stream and communications activities such as large file transfers. Each callback runs on an IO completion pool thread and completes quickly, processing a modest chunk and scheduling the next pass. Pending operations can be cancelled simply by calling `Close()` on the socket object. This is a great deal cheaper and more efficient than DIY thread management.

---

As already mentioned, `Abort()` is bad karma and should be avoided.

The material below was written prior to exclusion of the looping case from the question.

When long running processes loop they should *all* include an exit flag in their loop condition so that you can signal them to exit.

```
bool _run; //member of service class

//in OnStart
_run = true;

//in a method on some other thread
while ((yourLoopCondition) & _run) 
{ 
  //do stuff
  foreach (thing in things) 
  {
    //do more stuff
    if (!_run) break;
  }
}
if (!_run) CleanUp();

//in OnStop
_run = false;
```

Strictly you ought to use volatiles but since only the control logic ever sets the flag it doesn't matter. Technically a race condition exists but that just means you might go round one more time.

Comment: Long running threads are possible without loops. I had this problem with network connections and external processes. (And I'm still looking for a good solution to stop the threads.)

Comment: Yep, totally agree my long running process does not involve any looping so this solution is not an option.

Comment: What on EARTH are you doing that takes a long time without loops, copying a huge file?

Comment: If you can't signal to stop then Abort is your only option. Get ready to do some ugly cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Use ManualResetEvent to check if event is signalized, see sample at [Thread Synchronization (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: I might have the wrong end of the stick but I don't think this helps - if the worker thread is doing the long running section of code then it will not pick up the ManualResetEvent until it calls WaitOne().

Comment: ok, but yours threads have to check if event has arrived at time after time, in other form killing the thread is wrong. Your design of thread has to prevent shout down correctly and release all resources.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code I use for stopping threads in a Windows service (mind you I use Threads directly and not using thread pools):

```
// signal all threads to stop
this.AllThreadsStopSignal.Set();

if (logThreads.IsDebugEnabled)
    logThreads.Debug ("Stop workers");

// remember the time of the signal
DateTime signalTime = DateTime.Now;

// create an array of workers to be stopped
List<IServiceWorker> workersToBeStopped = new List<IServiceWorker> (workers);

while (true)
{
    // wait for some time
    Thread.Sleep (1000);

    // go through the list and see if any workers have stopped
    int i = 0;
    while (i < workersToBeStopped.Count)
    {
        IServiceWorker workerToBeStopped = workersToBeStopped [i];

        if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
            log.Debug (String.Format (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "Stopping worker '{0}'. Worker state={1}",
                workerToBeStopped.WorkerDescription,
                workerToBeStopped.WorkerState));

        bool stopped = workerToBeStopped.JoinThread (TimeSpan.Zero);

        // if stopped, remove it from the list
        if (stopped)
        {
            workersToBeStopped.RemoveAt (i);
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
                log.Debug (String.Format (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "Worker '{0}' was stopped.", workerToBeStopped.WorkerDescription));
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
                log.Debug (String.Format (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "Worker '{0}' could not be stopped, will try again later. Worker state={1}",
                    workerToBeStopped.WorkerDescription,
                    workerToBeStopped.WorkerState));
        }
    }

    // if all workers were stopped, exit from the loop
    if (workersToBeStopped.Count == 0)
        break;

    // check if the duration of stopping has exceeded maximum time
    DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan duration = nowTime - signalTime;

    if (duration > serviceCustomization.ThreadTerminationMaxDuration)
    {
        // execute forced abortion of all workers which have not stopped
        foreach (IServiceWorker worker in workersToBeStopped)
        {
            try
            {
                log.Warn (String.Format (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "Aborting worker '{0}.", worker.WorkerDescription));
                worker.Abort ();
                log.Warn (String.Format (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "Worker '{0}' aborted.", worker.WorkerDescription));
            }
            catch (ThreadStateException ex)
            {
                log.Warn (String.Format (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    "Worker '{0}' could not be aborted.", worker.WorkerDescription), ex);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your process is being shutdown anyway, I personally don't see the problem with using Abort().  I would try to find another way, but in the end, it doesn't matter **if** you'll be doing clean-up in the main thread anyway.

Another option would be to mark your worker threads as [background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) threads.  That way, they'll close automatically when the process closes.  You might be able to use the AppDomain.ProcessExit event to clean up before exiting.

Comment: I'd advise *never* using Abort.  I ignored this warning two years after .NET was released, and suffered a thousand cuts for it.  An abort may be thrown anywhere, completely hosing any and all assumptions, including clean "try...finally" behavior or say, half way into Add list logic in which case the count has been incremented but the item not added.  The only time I could conceive Abort being okay is for a process that has no side effects (IO) and is essentially just a big compute engine which during termination can safely have its memory corrupted.