# gracefully stopping a windows service with multithreaded processing on a timer thread?

Tags: windows, multithreading, service, timer

How to gracefully stop a windows service with multi-threaded processing on a timer thread? Is it possible to add some infinite loop logic in the OnStop method to postpone the service shutting down.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle cancellation of the threads in your service in the `OnStop()` method.
Try some logic with `ManualResetEvent` or `AutoResetEvent`
You probably also have to stop your timer.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use some sort of flag to indicate whether a Thread should stop or not. There is already a similar question on SO - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704991/how-to-stop-worker-threads-in-a-multithreaded-windows-service-on-service-stop)