# Find the source of a first chance exception raised in the Visual Studio 2010 Output window

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm working on a asp.net web application with Visual Studio 2010.  There are a bunch of output window messages during debugging regarding:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

and

> An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

I've read some great Q&A on the topic of [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973149/a-first-chance-exception-of-type-system-threading-threadabortexception-occurred) and [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777105/response-redirect-causes-system-threading-threadabortexception) these might be raised and [how to handle them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353270/how-can-i-detect-a-threadabortexception-in-a-finally-block-net) ([or not handle them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020374/a-first-chance-exception)).  My first guess is that it is related to Response.Redirect()s that are in the code.  However, I see them in the output and I'm not sure of the source of those output messages.

**Question: how do I determine *where* the first chance exception came from in Visual Studio 2010?**

Once I determine the source, I can investigate, solve or simply ignore per the Q&A linked to this question.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, unless there is specifically an error occurring as a result of these, these messages can generally be ignored.

I have read in the past that this can be solved by adding false to the second parameter of `Response.Redirect` to stop processing occurring after redirect.

E.g. `Response.Redirect("path/to/page.aspx", false);`

[Response.Redirect on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> When you use this method in a page handler to terminate a request for one page and start a new request for another page, set endResponse to false and then call the CompleteRequest() method. If you specify true for the endResponse parameter, this method calls the End method for the original request, which throws a ThreadAbortException exception when it completes. This exception has a detrimental effect on Web application performance, which is why passing false for the endResponse parameter is recommended. For more information, see the End method.

Comment: The linked questions show all of the ways of resolving, ignoring or otherwise dealing with these -- I am trying to determine "the where" they are coming from.

Comment: You can try pressing ```CTRL+ALT+E``` or ```CTRL D, E``` (can't remember which shortcut) or going to ```Debug > Exceptions``` and checking Thrown on all unchecked checkboxes. That might reveal what is the source of the exception.

Comment: I had a lot of hope for that idea, but despite checking all unchecked checkboxes for C++, CLR Exceptions, Win32, Managed Debugging Assistants, Native Run-Time Checks etc. -- no change in behavior.

Comment: Perhaps the message we see in the output window is the exception handling for the thread ending. I admit, when I first saw that, starting my new job, it frustrated me too that the supposed reason for it was "It just happens"!

Comment: To me it doesn't seem reasonable for asp.Net to let a thread exit in that way. It should end normally and return into the pool ready to pick up a new request.

Comment: I re-read my quoted text in my answer. The answer to _where_ this is coming from is the `End` method for the original request", so I assume `Response.End` - "... calls the End method for the original request, which throws a ThreadAbortException exception when it completes"

Comment: To avoid this exception, you could potentially catch the `ThreadAbortException` in the method you are calling the `Response.Redirect`, or the recommended way is to set the second parameter value to `false`. Then exit/return the function to prevent any code after the redirect from being evaluated.